# How to read tables in multiple docx files in a same folder by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have one folder called "Test_Plan". It consist multiple docx files and each docx file has multiple tables. My question is how can I read the whole docx files and give the output? For example, all docx files has multiple tables, I'm picking one docx file and give the output like

(i.e)
Total Number of Tables:  52
Total Number of YES Automations:  6
Total Number of NO Automations:  5

Like this I need to automate the whole number of files in that "Test_Plan" folder.
Hope you understand my question.

My code for read tables from single docx file:

```
#Module to retrive the word documents

from docx import Document
doc = Document("sample2.docx")


#Reading the tables in the particular docx

i = 0
for t in doc.tables:
    for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="ID" :
            i=i+1
print("Total Number of Tables: ", i)


#Counting the values of Automation
 # This will count how many yes automation

j=0
for table in doc.tables:
    for ro in table.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Automated Test Case" and (ro.cells[2].text=="yes" or ro.cells[2].text=="Yes"):
            j=j+1
print("Total Number of YES Automations: ", j)


#This part is used to count the No automation values

k = 0
for t in doc.tables:
    for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Automated Test Case" and (ro.cells[2].text=="no" or ro.cells[2].text=="No"):
            k=k+1
print("Total Number of NO Automations: ", k)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob to find all your files, e.g:

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('Test_Plan/*.docx'):
    doc = Document(name)
    ...
```

glob will return a list of file names that match the given pattern.  You can loop through that list,  as shown above by the for loop and open every file in turn.  After opening the files you can just plug in your code. 
Of course,  you will have to initialize your variables before the loop.

For splitting the file names I would suggest to use the following approach:

```
import os.path

path, filename = os.path.split(input)
```

Comment: Yeah, get back little later.

Comment: Hi Andreas I'm very new to python. so please explain bit higher.

Comment: See my explanations added to my answer.

Comment: Hi Andreas when i try to list my files in folder, the folder name also displaying. could you resolve it?

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what the problem is here, but you can always use `os.path.split` to split path and filename. I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I attached the image. I want only file name not with folder name.

Comment: @ArunBaskar, do `name = name.rsplit('/', 1)[1]` and then `doc = Document(name)`, this will consider the file name only.

Comment: See my addition to my previous answer.