# Reading multiple docx files in Python in one variable

Tags: python

In one of my folder there are total 5 word (.docx) files, I wants to read and store content of those files in dataframe

I am able to read one file using below syntax in Python. Can anyone help me how I can read multiple docx file stored in one folder and save results in dataframe

I am also not sure what will be name for docx file available in specific folder.

```
import docx2txt

# extract text
text = docx2txt.process("file.docx")
```

I am able to get results using below script

```
import os
import docx2txt
import glob
import pandas as pd       

os.chdir("C:/Data")

Descriptions = []
name = []

for file in glob.glob('*.docx'):
    Descriptions.append(docx2txt.process(file))    
    name.append(file)

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Descriptions': Descriptions,
     'Name': name,
    })

data.dtypes
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read tables in multiple docx files in a same folder by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910260/how-to-read-tables-in-multiple-docx-files-in-a-same-folder-by-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glob` to get all files in the folder then use `for loop` and append the output to the variable.

```
import glob
text = ''
for file in glob.glob('folder_name/*.docx'):
    text += docx2txt.process(file)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I able to build dataframe using your logic. I have updated script in my first query

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os

directory = '.'
extension = '.docx'
text = ''

for a_file in os.listdir(directory):
    if a_file.endswith(extension):
        text = docx2txt.process(a_file)
```